# Can not enable WiFi in Ubuntu 14.04, Lenovo Yoga 2 11

Tags: 14.04, networking, lenovo, wifi-hardware-switch, rfkill

This topic is beaten all over I know, but for this specific device, everything is extra weird. I have a Lenovo Yoga 2 11 “2-in-1” thing which is alright and has had Linux on it since the day I purchased it (2 yrs). It’s a UEFI machine (boo) but works well with Ubuntu and some proper Debian (yay) distros. I haven’t had any previous trouble using WiFi.

Yesterday I reinstalled 14.04 with a new (old) HDD in place of my recently failed Seagate. The drive is fine enough, and the wireless card is hooked up, but continues to show as hard blocked, or “WiFi is disabled by hardware switch.” I don’t have one. Fn+F7 is my combo but it doesn’t do a thing. Wireless is enabled in “BIOS.”

I’m no expert but have been using, ruining, and (mostly) fixing normal Linux systems for myself for several years. Even at that level we troubleshoot a ton but I cannot figure this one out.

Any advice?

Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter Adapter

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `rfkill list all` and also: `lsmod | grep idea`

Comment: Are you obliged to run 14.04? It's possible that more recent releases of Ubuntu have resolved your particular issue.